# copy files from /var/log/ folder to home directory

Tags: python

```
import os, shutil
source = os.listdir("var/log/")
base_destination = "/home/laptop/Desktop/"
file_name = 'demo.log'
for files in source:  # comparison
    if files == file_name:
        source_file_path = os.path.join('var/log/', 'demo.log')
        shutil.copyfile(source_file_path, base_destination)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions. Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Just copy file if it exists:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
import shutil
from pathlib import Path
p = Path('/var/log')
fname = 'demo.log'
print('\n'.join([f'{i}' for i in p.glob('*')]))  # list of files in /var/log/
origin = p / fname
target = Path.home() / 'Desktop'
if origin.exists():
    shutil.copyfile(f'{origin}', f'{target}')
```

Comment: Is *demo.log* in the printed list?